# Signed dll doesn't meet the custom 1 signing level requirements or violated code integrity policy

Tags: electron, windows-store-apps, code-signing, electron-builder, windows-store

I'm trying to get my Electron app approved to the app store. I have enabled the [audit mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s?form=MY01SV&OCID=MY01SV) on a VM. I'm running into this issue after installing the app with a signed appx.

The following log is found in the Event Viewer -> Application and Services Logs-> Microsoft-> Windows-> CodeIntegrity-> Operational.

> Code Integrity determined that a process
> (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\Company.App_Version_x64__identifier\app\Bar.exe)
> attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\Company.Bar_Version_x64__identifier\app\d3dcompiler_47.dll
> that did not meet the Custom 1 signing level requirements or violated
> code integrity policy (Policy
> ID:{a244370e-44c9-4c06-b551-f6016e563076}). However, due to code
> integrity auditing policy, the image was allowed to load.

I have the same issue twice more with `/app/swiftshader/libGLESv2.dll` and `/app/swiftshader/libEGL.dll`.

The dlls are being signed with :

```
  require("child_process").execSync(`<path>/signtool.exe sign /f ${CERTIFICATE_NAME} /p ${TOKEN_PASSWORD} /t http://timestamp.digicert.com ./dist/win-unpacked/${dllName}.dll`);
```

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Company.Bar_version_x64__identifier\app> `Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath .\*.dll,.\*.exe,.\swiftshader\*.dll`

```
    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Company.Bar_version_x64__identifier\app


SignerCertificate                         Status                                 Path
-----------------                         ------                                 ----
0011223344556677889911223344556677889900  Valid                                  d3dcompiler_47.dll11
0011223344556677889911223344556677889900  Valid                                  ffmpeg.dll
0011223344556677889911223344556677889900  Valid                                  libEGL.dll
0011223344556677889911223344556677889900  Valid                                  libGLESv2.dll
0011223344556677889911223344556677889900  Valid                                  vk_swiftshader.dll
0011223344556677889911223344556677889900  Valid                                  vulkan-1.dll
                                          NotSigned                              Bar.exe


    Directory: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Company.Bar_version_x64__identifier\app\swiftshader


SignerCertificate                         Status                                 Path
-----------------                         ------                                 ----
0011223344556677889911223344556677889900  Valid                                  libEGL.dll
0011223344556677889911223344556677889900  Valid                                  libGLESv2.dll
```

I'm not sure how to debug this issue, I did not have a lot of success by googling the available error message. The code is being signed by an official certificate that we paid for.